# C# - Sending Windows API messages to ListView in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, listview, openfiledialog

Below is some code which works beautifully on Windows XP, but does not work on Windows 7.  I'd like to know how to fix this for Windows 7, or perhaps a different approach...

I'm developing a C# application where I would like to launch a generic OpenFileDialog browser and have a particular file in the list pre-selected.  As far as I can tell, the OpenFileDialog itself does not support selecting a particular file in the list, so I took to the Windows API to send messages directly to the handle of the ListView.

In UISpy, the ListView in the OpenFileDialog window is identified as ClassName=SysListView32 in Windows XP.  In Windows 7 however this list is identified by ClassName=DUIListView.  I cannot seem to find any documentation for the DUI library.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LV_ITEM
{
    public uint mask;
    public int iItem;
    public int iSubItem;
    public uint state;
    public uint stateMask;
    public IntPtr pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public IntPtr lParam;
}

//get a handle to the ListView object 
//    findList is my own function which drills down through the UI tree for me
AutomationElement list = findList("Title of containing window", "Name of List in UISpy");
int handle_list = list.Current.NativeWindowHandle;

//some constants right out of CommCtrl.h
const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
const int LVM_SETITEMSTATE = LVM_FIRST + 43;
const int LVIS_FOCUSED = 0x0001;
const int LVIS_SELECTED = 0x0002;

//build a LV_ITEM object to send in the API message
LV_ITEM lvi = new LV_ITEM();
lvi.stateMask = LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED;
lvi.state = LVIS_FOCUSED | LVIS_SELECTED;

//pick the index number of the file to select in the ListView
int wParam = 8;

IntPtr ptrLvi = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(lvi));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(lvi, ptrLvi, false);

//send the message to the ListView!!
SendMessage(new IntPtr(handle_list), LVM_SETITEMSTATE, new IntPtr(wParam), ptrLvi);
```

Does anyone know the correct way to interface with the new DUIListView object?  Does anyone know a different approach I can take to accomplish this task?  Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried setting your target machine as `x86`? I doubt that your `Windows 7` is a `x64` system and many `win32` functions/functionalities don't work well in `x64` system.

Comment: The code was tested successfully on WinXP x86 and the troublesome environment is Win7 x64.  Is there an equivalent to the user32.dll for use on x64 platforms?

Comment: what is your application target? I think it should be `x86`.

Comment: application target is x86.  just found out that we link in other x86-only libraries, so we do not build for x64.